# Is "settings" needed in hook_field_widget_info()?

Tags: entities

[hook_field_formatter_info()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_formatter_info/7) and [hook_field_widget_info](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_info/7&ei=u9q5UebnG6aJ7AaN34GIDA&usg=AFQjCNFTv6NB3SjXUhTIfXwsPlRqpZaUTg&sig2=Fynbzxl1QXvznO0ej2aZpw&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bGE&cad=rjt) return an array containing a "settings" index. I want to know when is it used. What happens if it is empty, or just omitted?

My formatter and widget for my custom field **does** have settings. It's just that during widget/formatter definition the settings are not known yet.

Comment: Why not try it and find out? :)

Comment: @Clive It's a little bit complicated! Maybe you could look at https://drupal.org/sandbox/lo2y4/2018089‎ if you  had time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hooks your module implements don't set that array index, the function invoking them will set them to an empty array. See [_field_info_collate_types()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/_field_info_collate_types/7).

```
  foreach (module_implements('field_widget_info') as $module) {
    $widget_types = (array) module_invoke($module, 'field_widget_info');
    foreach ($widget_types as $name => $widget_info) {
      // Provide defaults.
      $widget_info += array(
        'settings' => array(),
      );
      $info['widget types'][$name] = $widget_info;
      $info['widget types'][$name]['module'] = $module;
    }
  }
```

```
  foreach (module_implements('field_formatter_info') as $module) {
    $formatter_types = (array) module_invoke($module, 'field_formatter_info');
    foreach ($formatter_types as $name => $formatter_info) {
      // Provide defaults.
      $formatter_info += array(
        'settings' => array(),
      );
      $info['formatter types'][$name] = $formatter_info;
      $info['formatter types'][$name]['module'] = $module;
    }
  }
```

It is then up to the module implementing those hooks, and any related one, to correctly handle the values for that array index, even in the case another module changes it to a value the module is not expecting.

Comment: Does any part of core depend on 'settings'? (my module doesn't). tnx

Comment: Not that I know of. It's the module implementing the formatter or the widget that depends from that, eventually. There is the Field UI module that could use that array index, but I think it just passes it to the necessary hooks.